# How to enable `WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN ` in Spring MVC converter

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I hope to enable `WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN` feature in Spring MVC. How can I customise the `serialization` for `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customise Jackson in Spring Boot 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263553/how-to-customise-jackson-in-spring-boot-1-4)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

`@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizeObjectMapper() {
        return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToEnable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN);
    }`