# InvalidFormatException for Date - fixing without using JsonFormat or modifying original class

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-cloud, json-deserialization, spring-cloud-feign

### Introduction

We are using a custom starter hosted on a nexus repository, that contains spring-cloud-feign clients that make requests to microservices.

One of the microservices returns the dates as "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ssZ" and this works in most of our applications. However, we have one application that is throwing the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2019-10-16 14:23:17": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2019-10-16 14:23:17': Unparseable date: "2019-10-16 14:23:1
7")
```

### Current work-around

My Current work-around, as I don't want to pollute the starter, is to extend the class and create a local feign-client and local pojo with the proper JsonFormat:

```
public class DocumentMetaDataFix extends DocumentMetaData {
    @JsonFormat(
        shape = Shape.STRING,
        pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    )
    private Date creationDate;
    @JsonFormat(
        shape = Shape.STRING,
        pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    )
```

### Failed Fixes

I have tried the following in my configuration class, in order to try affecting the de-serialization from another path. However, the DocumentMetaDataSerializer is never called. The ObjectMapper bean IS called.

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomBigDecimalDeserialization() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
                jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializerByType(DocumentMetaData.class, new DocumentMetaDataDeserializer());
            }

        };
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        //mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public Module dynamoDemoEntityDeserializer() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(DocumentMetaData.class, new DocumentMetaDataDeserializer());
        return module;
    }

    public static class DocumentMetaDataDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DocumentMetaData> {
        @Override
        public DocumentMetaData deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            // return DynamoDemoEntity instance;

            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);


            return null;
        }

        public DocumentMetaData deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer t) throws IOException {
            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);


            return null;
        }

    }
```

### Full Stacktrace

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2019-10-16 14:23:17": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2019-10-16 14:23:17': Unparseable date: "2019-10-16 14:23:1
7")
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 580] (through reference chain: eu.europa.ec.nova.documentstore.DocumentMetaData["creationDate"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1548)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:910)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:524)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:467)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateBasedDeserializer._parseDate(DateDeserializers.java:195)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:285)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:268)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:237)
        ... 70 common frames omitted
```

**So, any ideas?** 
I have searched through the project for references to Jackson in case there is anything else in my project causing this.

**I am will try to go inside the ObjectMapper and try to debug the current parameters/fields of the configuration at ObjectMapper.java:3084 from the stacktace:**

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:237)
... 67 common frames omitted
```

### Update

I added a breakpoint in the objectmapper constructor, and am seeing that it is being initialized from more than one location. This led me to suspect that spring-boot is not using my ObjectMapper. Instead it is using an internal spring one that is called from `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` .

```
<init>:480, ObjectMapper
build:606, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
<init>:59, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
<init>:74, AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
```

I will therefore try to over-ride this internal spring one, based on results I found from: [How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper implicitly used by Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot)

**However this also failed.**

References

1. [Is it possible to configure Jackson custom deserializers at class level for different data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462381/is-it-possible-to-configure-jackson-custom-deserializers-at-class-level-for-diff)
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper
3. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
4. **very useful:** https://mostafa-asg.github.io/post/customize-json-xml-spring-mvc-output/
5. [How to customise Jackson in Spring Boot 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263553/how-to-customise-jackson-in-spring-boot-1-4)

### Update - final list of tries

**It still fails with an error.**

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    builder.serializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.createXmlMapper(true).build()));

    //converters.add(cmsaMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}


@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomBigDecimalDeserialization() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializerByType(DocumentMetaData.class, new DocumentMetaDataDeserializer());
        }

    };
}


@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    //mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
public Module dynamoDemoEntityDeserializer() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(DocumentMetaData.class, new DocumentMetaDataDeserializer());
    return module;
}

public static class DocumentMetaDataDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DocumentMetaData> {
    @Override
    public DocumentMetaData deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // return DynamoDemoEntity instance;

        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);


        return null;
    }

    public DocumentMetaData deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer t) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);


        return null;
    }

}
```

**It still fails with an error.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using LocalDateTime,
this is what I'm doing and working for me

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime date;
```