# Jackson set global date format for all Date fields

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, jackson

I am working on **non spring boot** project.

There are plenty of data objects and it is starting to get inconvenient to annotate all date fields with JsonFormat.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = JacksonSerialiser.DATE_FORMAT)
private Date someDate;
```

I know I can set date format directly on the ObjectMapper

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
OBJECT_MAPPER.setDateFormat(simpleDateFormat);
```

This works if all serialization/deserialization is done directly using the object mapper.

You could implement CustomDateSerializer by extending `StdSerializer<Date>`, but again in order for the format to be applied you need to specify this on field level like so:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
public Date someDate;
```

With spring boot there is property you can use:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Would be great if I can set such property without spring.

Comment: Spring does that magic for you because it creates a bean of `ObjectMapper` which is a singleton probably. So in a non-spring project you could create a static factory method or something like this, which you would call where you need to do the serialization/deserialization to obtain the configured object mapper with your custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to implement your own `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` and expose it as a bean. Then you can put your date transformation customizations there with a custom serializer and deserializer. Then the default object mapper will have your customization and everything downstream will automatically inherit from it.

Related example 
[How to customise Jackson in Spring Boot 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263553/how-to-customise-jackson-in-spring-boot-1-4)

Comment: The guy said that he is not working on a spring boot project.  I would hate to down-vote your suggestion, but you should answer in the context that the guy is asking.

Comment: Check the edit and timestamp @SteveStorck