# Globally configure Jackson to serialize Date's in UTC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I've a Spring Boot application with an API. Some of the endpoints returns responses with data serialised from `OffsetDateTime`. Some of these dates comes from the database and others are generated at runtime (`OffsetDateTime.now()`), which cause the `OffsetDateTime` to have different timezones. I like to keep using the `OffsetDateTime` on my API to respons the time zone, but I would like all dates serialised from my API to be in the same timezone -- in my case UTC. How can I globally configure Jackson to do that?

Comment: Which database you are using ?

Comment: How are you normally serializing `OffsetDateTime` fields? Are you using `@JsonFormat`?

Comment: @Andreas I've tried using `@JsonFormat(timezone = "UTC")` but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
```

JVM Default Timezone:

```
@PostConstruct
void started() {
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Comment: The `setDefault` make my OffsetDateTimes created using `OffsetDateTime.now()` being in UTC, which makes them UTC when serialized using Jackson. That's good, but if I somehow creates an OffsetDateTime in another time zone, it's still returned in that timezone. The Spring Boot properties does not seem to work properly.

Comment: @dhrm In that case you will need to manually convert to UTC. Or create a custom serializer and add it globally, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051029/4279074